# BooleanField in V4 does not accept Mui Icons anymore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, icons, react-admin

In react-admin v3 I used the following functional component:

```js
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear'
import DoneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Done'
import get from 'lodash/get'
import { BooleanField, BooleanFieldProps, useRecordContext } from 'react-admin'

const EventBooleanField = (props: BooleanFieldProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { source, label, valueLabelTrue } = props
  const record = useRecordContext(props)

  const falseIcon = () => <ClearIcon data-testid="false" color="disabled" />
  const trueIcon = () => <DoneIcon data-testid="true" color="success" />

  return (
    <BooleanField
      sortable={false}
      source={source}
      valueLabelTrue={`${label}: ${get(record, valueLabelTrue)}`}
      valueLabelFalse={`${label}: -`}
      TrueIcon={trueIcon}
      FalseIcon={falseIcon}
    />
  )
}
export default EventBooleanField
```

After upgrading to v4 the last two props throw an error:

```
Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }'.
  Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '{ muiName: string; }'
```

How can I use a Mui icon for type `OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue because the new api constraint to `SvgIconComponent`. I resolved this issue by using the line code below.

```
import { SvgIcon } from "@mui/material"
import { Warning, CheckCircle } from "@mui/icons-material"

const NotApprovedIcon: typeof SvgIcon = (props) => {
  return <Warning color="error" {...props} />
}
NotApprovedIcon.muiName = "NotApprovedIcon"

const ApprovedIcon: typeof SvgIcon = (props) => {
  return <CheckCircle color="success" {...props} />
}
ApprovedIcon.muiName = "NotApprovedIcon"

...
<BooleanField 
  source="approve" 
  FalseIcon={NotApprovedIcon}
  TrueIcon={ApprovedIcon} textAlign="center" />
...
```